# Heatmap in R returns blank plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map with the below code.

```
library(ggplot2)
RO_diff1_10 <- c(0.003197056,  0.031952193 , 0.317694767,  0.631357229 , 1.548588179,  3.000675013 , 5.635730267 ,11.710554504, 17.424381041, 14.318469977,8.099506073 , 4.264751628,  1.761246406  ,0.890215117,  0.595636681 , 0.447541540,  0.298905526 , 0.179605462,  0.089901266,0.044975304,0.017996047)

RO_diff1_100 <- c(0.008513677,0.085095597  ,0.846852831,  1.684645430  ,4.144564377,  8.071515418, 15.314786741, 32.831856543, 51.552068405 ,64.110304328, 49.007935109, 32.837083396, 16.467462320 , 8.991137813 , 6.183440560 , 4.711966796 , 3.192501503 , 1.940794781  ,0.980101675 , 0.4925131, 0.197600907)

vectorC_WT <- c( 1.0e-03, 1.0e-02, 1.0e-01, 2.0e-01, 5.0e-01, 1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 5.0e+00, 1.0e+01, 5.0e+01, 1.0e+02, 2.0e+02, 5.0e+02, 1.0e+03, 1.5e+03, 2.0e+03, 3.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 1.0e+04, 2.0e+04, 5.0e+04)


df11 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x=vectorC_WT, y=10, RO_diff = RO_diff1_10))
df12 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x=vectorC_WT, y=100, RO_diff = RO_diff1_100))

dfheat <- rbind(df11,df12)

ggplot(data=dfheat, aes(x, y, fill=RO_diff)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000), limits=c(0.001,20000))+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(10,100))
```

The issue is that it returns me with a blank graph .. Any suggestions why this may be happening?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer suggested by @monte can give you a heatmap, but does not quite answer your question, which is *why are you not seeing any of the data?*  You're seeing a plot and the scale, so what you're not actually seeing is the result of `geom_tile()`.  The simple reason is that **you set your axis limits too small and it is clipping off the data.**

The argument of `limits=` within `scale_*_log10()` is acting very much like `ylim()` or `xlim()`, which [results in removal of any data outside of that range in your plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html).  This may not make sense, because, after all, your y values in `dfheat` are 10 and 100... so if the limits are 10 to 100, it should show that, right?  Well, yes and no.  Yes, it can show points that exist at y=10 and y=100... but `geom_tile()` does not work like that.  For `geom_tile()`, the x and y aesthetic indicates the center of a rectangle with `width=` and `height=` dimensions.  That means the maximum value of a point at y=100 will be a bit greater than 100 and the minimum value of y=10 will be a bit below 10.  Furthermore, on a log scale, the numbers tend to be a bit exaggerated, (in order to view them).  We can show this clearly if you add `geom_point()` to your plot:

```
ggplot(data=dfheat, aes(x, y, fill=RO_diff)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000), limits=c(0.001,20000))+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(10,100))
```

[image]

So, the points are within the limits, because they are points, but the tiles are outside your y axis limits.  We can get those to show up if you increase your limit range, but remember, it's a log scale now, so you have to adjust larger than you think (1 log unit is usually safe):

```
ggplot(data=dfheat, aes(x, y, fill=RO_diff)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000), limits=c(0.001,20000))+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000))
```

[image]

Notice anything now?  Those points at the extremes of the x axis are also not showing their tiles for the same reason.  The fix is also the same: extend by one log unit.  I will also use `width=` and `height=` for `geom_tile()` to get the tiles to look more "heat-mappy" and use `alpha=` to indicate where we have overlapping tiles:

```
ggplot(data=dfheat, aes(x, y, fill=RO_diff)) +
  geom_tile(width=0.2, height=1, alpha=0.8) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_viridis()+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000), limits=c(0.0001,100000))+
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1,1000))
```

[image]

*If you want to go further with this, I'd recommend playing around with the `width=` argument for `geom_tile()` to try to get those to meet up.  Basically, you'll need to set it in the `aes(width=...some log10 transformation...)` to get it to work out.  I played a bit, but did not find something that worked perfectly.*

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get blank plot is because your `x` and `y` are still numeric i.e. to say they are still continuous. As in general, the heatmap makes sense for categorical data, i.e. to say `x` and `y` both are factors. So if you convert your `x` and `y` values to `factor` you will be able to plot a heatmap.
But then, `log` doesn't make sense for factors, hence your last lines would throw an error. So the workaround to plot log values, is to work convert `x` and `y` values to log and then to factor and then you can plot the heatmap.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
RO_diff1_10 <- c(0.003197056,  0.031952193 , 0.317694767,  0.631357229 , 1.548588179,  3.000675013 , 5.635730267 ,11.710554504, 17.424381041, 14.318469977,8.099506073 , 4.264751628,  1.761246406  ,0.890215117,  0.595636681 , 0.447541540,  0.298905526 , 0.179605462,  0.089901266,0.044975304,0.017996047)

RO_diff1_100 <- c(0.008513677,0.085095597  ,0.846852831,  1.684645430  ,4.144564377,  8.071515418, 15.314786741, 32.831856543, 51.552068405 ,64.110304328, 49.007935109, 32.837083396, 16.467462320 , 8.991137813 , 6.183440560 , 4.711966796 , 3.192501503 , 1.940794781  ,0.980101675 , 0.4925131, 0.197600907)

vectorC_WT <- c( 1.0e-03, 1.0e-02, 1.0e-01, 2.0e-01, 5.0e-01, 1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 5.0e+00, 1.0e+01, 5.0e+01, 1.0e+02, 2.0e+02, 5.0e+02, 1.0e+03, 1.5e+03, 2.0e+03, 3.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 1.0e+04, 2.0e+04, 5.0e+04)


dfheat <- data.frame(
  x= rep(round(log10(vectorC_WT),2),2), 
  y = c(
    rep(10, length(vectorC_WT)),
    rep(100, length(vectorC_WT))
    ),
  RO_diff= log10(c(RO_diff1_10, RO_diff1_100))
)

ggplot(data=dfheat, aes(as.factor(x), as.factor(y), fill=RO_diff)) +
  geom_tile() +  
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  labs(x='x', y= 'y')
```

The above code, produces the following chart.
[image]